# Как добавить/включить увеличение фото в Masonry Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, zoom

Здравствуйте! На сайте использую плагин masonry для портфолио. Скажите, как добавить возможность открытия фото в iframe при нажатии, к примеру, т.е. увеличить его?

Или посоветуйте лучшие плагины для такого дела.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Порекомендую вам галерею [blueimp Gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/), которой сам пользуюсь, в том числе и с Masonry. На сайте проекта (по ссылке выше) перейдите к разделу "Lightbox image gallery", и пощелкайте по изображениям.

Галерея подключается [стандартным способом](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#setup), никаких тонкостей с Masonry не будет, т.к. плагины не конфликтуют друг с другом.

1. Подключаете файлы `blueimp-gallery.js` и `jquery.blueimp-gallery.js`
2. Каждое изображение в Masonry оборачиваете ссылкой на него же с атрибутом `data-gallery="mygallery"`

Вот пример верстки одного отдельного изображения:

```
<a href="yourimage.jpg" data-gallery="mygallery">
  <img src="yourimage.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Все изображения с одинаковым ключом (`mygallery` в примере) плагин покажет в единой галерее (изображения можно будет пролистывать в режиме просмотра). Если пролистывание вам не нужно - тогда задавайте уникальный ключ в `data-gallery` у каждого изображения.